# Error when updating table in MySQL DB via Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

Hey guys,

I have a Java application which reads .csv files, creates instances with the information and I then upload the instances to a MySQL database.
The first upload always works perfectly.

But if I then decide to upload the same files again, an error occurs. Up until this afternoon there was no error, but now I can not get rid of it. 
So I am using Envers `(@Audited)`, which allows me to keep track of changes performed to the tables. 
-> I am expecting the exact same data to be uploaded again, but it is not.

Since this afternoon I keep getting this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private long dto.Project.id] by reflection for
>   persistent property [dto.Project#id] : 1

Then, sometimes, I also get this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private long dto.Device.ID_FDEV] by reflection for
>   persistent property [dto.Device#ID_FDEV] : 152372

I checked that every field has its getter and setter, which is the case.

So as mentioned above, this has worked fine until a few hours ago. And I can not really recall having changed anything that could have any impact on it. 
I checked the code / compared it to earlier versions but that did not help.

According to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10618 this is supposed to be a bug in Hibernate, but as it had worked before I can not quite believe that.

Just in case I have just tried all the old versions and for some reason I keep getting this error.

Thanks in advance and hopefully somehow has an idea because it is driving me crazy.

@Edit:
The error also occurs when I want to upload a second, different project to the database using the same instance of the application. What am I doing wrong all of a sudden !?

@Edit2:
Sorry, I forgot to post some code.

```
    public void add(Object object) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction t = null;
    try {
        t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        session.flush();
        t.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

So obviously this is my function that uploads my data from the application to the DB.

```
private void upload() {
    Project project = new Project();
    String[] details = projectDetails.split(";");
    project.setTitle(details[0]);
    project.setPROJEKT1(details[1]);
    project.setPROJEKT2(details[2]);
    project.setPROJEKT3(details[3]);
    project.setDATUM(details[4]);
    if (connection.checkIfProjectExistant(project)) {
        project = connection.getProject(project.getTitle());
    }

    for (Device device : deviceList) {
        device.setProject(project);
        for (DeviceElement element : device.getDeviceElement()) {
            element.setUploadTime(new Date());
        }

    }
    project.setDeviceList(deviceList);

    connection.add(project);
}
```

So in this part I set some of the fields of the project before uploading the project. 
If the project already exists in the DB, I "download" this project again and create an instance of it and then pass it to the current project. Basically this just avoids having 10 different projects in the DB, which are all the same(because the Project_ID is a auto-generated, incremented value). 
So the aim is that I always update this one project.

```
package dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Entity(name = "Project")
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

// Attribute
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PROJECT_ID", unique = true)
private long id;
```

This is what the "Project" class looks like.

@Edit3:

I noticed that I had not used printstacktrace, so I can give you more details about the error now:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int dto.Device.id] by reflection for persistent property [dto.Device#id] : 1
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at application.MyConnection.add(MyConnection.java:107)
    at application.MainController.upload(MainController.java:956)
    at application.MainController.btnUpload(MainController.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int dto.Device.id] by reflection for persistent property [dto.Device#id] : 1
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4735)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.tools.EntityTools.getIdentifier(EntityTools.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.tools.EntityTools.entitiesEqual(EntityTools.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.ToOneIdMapper.checkModified(ToOneIdMapper.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.ToOneIdMapper.mapToMapFromEntity(ToOneIdMapper.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.MultiPropertyMapper.map(MultiPropertyMapper.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.work.ModWorkUnit.<init>(ModWorkUnit.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl.onPostUpdate(EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field dto.Device.id to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
    ... 73 more
```

@Edit4:
Mapping .cfg.xml file:

```
<mapping class="dto.Project"/>
<mapping class="dto.DeviceElement"/>
<mapping class="dto.Device"/>
```

Mapping in Device.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Table(name = "DEVICE")
public class Device {

    // Attribute
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    private int id;
```

.
.
.

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROJECT_ID")
    private Project project;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<DeviceElement> deviceElement = new ArrayList<DeviceElement>();
```

Mapping in DeviceElement.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Table(name = "DEVICE_ELEMENT")
public class DeviceElement {

    // Attribute
    @Id
    private long ID;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Device device;
```

Okay, so I just noticed something weird.
I want to use envers, because I will be uploading the same projects, but perhaps some of the attributes of the subclasses have changed.

But what I do not understand is how I keep getting the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int dto.Device.id] by reflection for persistent property [dto.Device#id] : 1
```

when I am actually not even touching the device id? 
As it is an auto-increment Primary Key, it should just be incremented?
But for some reason something tries to set the id, I just do not get what..

Comment: Can you please chunk of code here, so we can help more

Comment: sure sorry, I totally forgot

Comment: there is a bug is in version 5.0 and 5.1.0 what is your hibernate version

Comment: I'm using final 5.2. but how come it worked fine all this time and all of a sudden the bug occurs?

Comment: If you continue to get this problem, please open a jira with a small test case and we can look into it.  AFAIK, this shouldn't be an issue at least with 5.2.

Comment: I just added the complete error now, maybe that provides more info for you to help me

Comment: Could you also include your mappings for `Device` and `DeviceElement`.  I've been trying to replicate the issue but I've been unsuccessful.  Perhaps its something in your mappings.

Comment: I am awfully sorry for not responding any sooner and apologize. I understand if you can not be bothered anymore to look into this anymore. I was busy doing other stuff, so really sorry again. In case you do still want to look into this, I will provide your requested information.

Comment: Also, I updated the error code, as, luckily, I was able to change the Primary Key of the Device.class to an auto-increment id, which makes things a little easier for me. Never the less, the erorr I keep getting makes no sense ( it is still the same as with the last error code btw ). Anyway, I added it all to the post above.